# ¿Cómo puedo tomar el dato 0 de un arreglo y ponerlo en otro arreglo que se encuentra en otra clase?

Tags: java-8

Tengo una lista de "pacientes" que se encuentra en un arreglo1, Quiero pasar el primero que esta en a la posición 0 a otro arreglo2 llamado "atendidos" que esta en otra clase

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Podrías compartir, al menos, la definición de los datos y clases de origen y destino? ¿En qué momento quieres hacer esa copia o desde qué clase querrás hacerlo?

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pacientes es el arreglo que contiene la información, lo tienes que declarar como public static en tu clase, y en la clase de atendidos tienes que crear un objeto tipo Pacientes quedando de la siguiente forma.

clase pacientes:

```
public static String array1[] = new String[1];
public void llenarPacientes(){
array1[0]="paciente 1";
}
```

y en tu clase de atendidos:

```
String atendidos[] = new String[1];
Pacientes paciente = new Pacientes();
//si no haz cargado los datos previamente lo puedes utilizar con el siguiente método de lo contrario omite esto
paciente.llenarPacientes();
atendidos[0]=persona.array1[0];
```

En donde `[0]` es la posición del elemento que se desea transferir.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Tu código funcionaría si ambas matrices están definidas en el mismo método o clase. Cuando son datos alojados en clases diferentes no funciona como pones en tu código.

Comment: Efectivamente, no me fije que estaba mencionando que el arreglo estaba en otra clase.